# Driving Direction Windows Store Apps with Bing Maps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

Currently, I am developing Windows Store Apps. I want to Ask, how to show driving direction in my application?
I want to apps detects current location and I have destination coordinates
thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried????? This is not a place that you just come to get free code. According to the stack overflow guidelines you need to show some effort, ANY effort to solving the problem already. If you have tried something, post it. If not, please go research it a little and come back, or post this question on the Programmers stack exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Google search leads me to [Driving route path direction with Bing Maps in C#/XAML in a Windows 8 app](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/461691/Driving-route-path-direction-with-Bing-Maps-in-Csh)